# AUTO_INCREMENT personalizado

Tags: php, mysql

eu tenho em um db MYSQL duas tabelas que são ligadas:

- ADMIN

  `id - nome - empresa`

Cada admin adiciona vários valores na tabela docs:

- DOCS

  `id_doc - id_admim_doc - doc - valor`

A coluna `id_admim_doc` é uma chave estrangeira da tabela `admin`, o que eu quero exatamente é que a cada novo registro com o msm `id_admim_doc` seja adicionado um `doc` com `AUTO_INCREMENTE` tipo assim: `doc_1`, `doc_2`...

Porem cada lista de cada `admin` deve se preencher de forma independente, ou seja, no `admin` 1 tem `doc_1`, `doc_2`... E no `admin` 2 também. Ex: O `admin` 1 tem sla, 20 docs o 2 tem só 3, e assim por diante. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Ex:

```
Admin:

id -   nome -    empresa
 1  -  teste  -  teste2
 2  -  teste3 -  teste4


 Docs:

 id_doc    - id_admim_doc -    doc    - valor
   1       -     1        -   doc_1   -    t
   2       -     1        -   doc_2   -    t
   3       -     1        -   doc_3   -    t
   4       -     2        -   doc_1   -    t
   5       -     2        -   doc_2   -    t
   6       -     1        -   doc_4   -    t
   7       -     2        -   doc_3   -    t
   8       -     1        -   doc_5   -    t
```

Comment: Poderia melhorar sua pergunta? Não ficou muito clara.

Comment: @Guerra, cara, olha o exemplo final, é meio que seria um `auto_increment` para cada `id_admin_doc` diferente, saca? Veja lá, todos q tem o valor 1, tem os docs 1,2,3,4 e 5, veja que com valor 2 tem 1,2 e 3, caso eu adicionasse mais um doc pro `admin` com id 2, o novo doc dele seria 4, e se fosse do `admin` com id 1, o doc seria 6, entende?

Comment: E se houvesse um novo `admin` com id 3, aí começaria um novo pra ele, doc_1, 2 ,3...

Comment: Usa trigger pra fazer isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar trigger para fazer isso usando trigger o que deixaria seu `insert` pequeno

Aí quando você for inserir o campo `doc` você insere como `null`

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `trg_atualiza_doc`;

DELIMITER $$

  CREATE TRIGGER `trg_atualiza_doc`
    BEFORE INSERT ON `docs` 
       FOR EACH ROW 
         BEGIN
             SET @total := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM docs WHERE id_admin_doc = NEW.id_admin_doc);          
             SET @nome := concat( 'DOC_',@total + 1,'');
             SET NEW.doc = @nome;
         END $$

DELIMITER ;
```